# Python Multiprocessing Exception Handling Data Chunking

Tags: python, exception, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying to speed up some data processing using the multiprocessing module, the idea being I can send a chunk of data to each process I start up to utilize all the cores on my machine instead of just one at a time.

So I built an iterator for the data using the pandas read_fwf() function, with chunksize=50000 lines at a time.  My problem is that eventually the iterator should raise StopIteration, and I'm trying to catch this in an except block in the child process and pass it along to the parent thread using a Queue to let the parent know it can stop spawning child processes.  I have no idea what's wrong though, but what's happening is it gets to the end of the data and then keeps spawning processes which essentially do nothing.

```
def MyFunction(data_iterator, results_queue, Placeholder, message_queue):

    try:
        current_data = data_iterator.next()
        #does other stuff here
        #that isn't important
        placeholder_result = "Eggs and Spam"
        results_queue.put(placeholder_result)
        return None
    except StopIteration:
        message_queue.put("Out Of Data")
        return None

results_queue = Queue()  #for passing results from each child process
message_queue = Queue()  #for passing the stop iteration message
cpu_count = cpu_count()  #num of cores on the machine
Data_Remaining = True    #loop control
output_values = []       #list to put results in
print_num_records = 0    #used to print how many lines have been processed
my_data_file = "some_data.dat"
data_iterator = BuildDataIterator(my_data_file)

while Data_Remaining:

    processes = []
    for process_num in range(cpu_count):
        if __name__ == "__main__":

            p = Process(target=MyFunction, args=(data_iterator,results_queue,Placeholder, message_queue))  
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()
            print "Process " + str(process_num) + " Started"          #print some stuff to 
            print_num_records = print_num_records + 50000             #show how far along
            print "Processing records through: ", print_num_records   #my data file I am

    for i,p in enumerate(processes):
        print "Joining Process " + str(i)
        output_values.append(results_queue.get())
        p.join(None)

    if not message_queue.empty():
        message = message_queue.get()
    else:
        message = ""
    if message == "Out Of Data":
        Data_Remaining = False
        print "STOP ITERATION NOW PLEASE"
```

Update:
I discovered a problem with the data iterator.  There are approximately 8 million rows in my data set, and after it processes the 8 million it never actually returns a StopIteration, it keeps returning the same 14 rows of data over and over.  Here is the code that builds my data iterator:

```
def BuildDataIterator(my_data_file):

    #data_columns is a list of 2-tuples
    #headers is a list of strings
    #num_lines is 50000

    data_reader = read_fwf(my_data_file, colspecs=data_columns, header=None, names=headers, chunksize=num_lines)

    data_iterator = data_reader.__iter__()

    return data_iterator
```

Comment: I'd start by putting *everything* except `MyFunction` in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. You don't want the worker processes to run that code at all, right?

Comment: Right, I don't want the worker processes to run the code, but I haven't had any problems getting the worker processes to start, I'm having a problem getting the main thread to terminate.